# Regular Languages Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, automata, regular-language

I need help proving the following question:

Let $L$ be any regular language on $\sum{a,b}$. Show that an algorithm exists for determining if L contains any strings of even length.

So far, I know that since $L$ is regular, then there exists a dfa. 
And if $L$ contains no even-length strings, then $L$ intersection $L ((aa + ab + ba + bb)*)$ = the empty set.

How do i show that an algorithm exists?

Comment: You're almost there. Do you know the algorithm for computing the product of two automata?

Comment: FWIW the question is badly phrased: the existence of an algorithm depends on the representation of $L$ which you are given. If you're given a DFA then yes, there is an algorithm, as Johannes has hinted. If you're given an infinite sequence of words in $L$ then there isn't an algorithm.

Comment: @peter-taylor When dealing with decidability questions about regular languages, it is usually understood that the language is given by a DFA, NFA, regular expression or a linear grammar. BTW, the second part of your comment is not quite true. There might be an algorithm in some cases, even if L is not recursively enumerable. For instance, if L is any language containing at least one nonempty word, then LL always contains a word of even length.

Answer (score 1):

The best proof that such algorithm exists is to present it ;-)

First of all, since you want to answer *if* language $L$ contains any word of even length, and not required to give an *example* of such word, you can map all the letters to a single symbol. Then you could just try all the words of length $2k \leq 2(n + 1)$.

In fact, if you are given an automaton, you could take word $a^n$ and while running it note if you were at any accepting state after even letter (that is, you don't need to try all the words, because shorter words $a^{2k}$ are prefixes of the $a^n$).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Conputing $L \cap (A^2)^*$ is the generic solution, but given the very specific form of your problem, there is an alternative way. I will try to explain it on an example. Consider the following automaton $\mathcal{A}$ [image: automaton]
<sub>(source: [jep at www.irif.fr](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejep/StackExchange/Images/Automaton1.jpg))</sub>

Its transitions are given in the following table
\begin{align*}
 &|\ \ 1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 5\\
\hline
a &|\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 3\ \ 4\\
\hline
b &|\ \ 0\ \ 5\ \ 4\ \ 3\ \ 4 
\end{align*}
Now, consider the set $\{aa, ab, ba, bb\}$ of all words of length $2$ as a new alphabet and compute the transitions generated by these four words.
\begin{align*}
 &|\ \ 1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 5\\
\hline
aa &|\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 3\\
ab &|\ \ 5\ \ 4\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 3\\
ba &|\ \ 0\ \ 4\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 3\\
bb &|\ \ 0\ \ 4\ \ 3\ \ 4\ \ 3
\end{align*}
This leads you to the following automaton $\mathcal{A}_2$ [image: automaton 2]
<sub>(source: [jep at www.irif.fr](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejep/StackExchange/Images/Automaton2.jpg))</sub>

which, after reduction (state $3$ is useless), gives you the automaton $\mathcal{A}_3$ [image: automaton 3]
<sub>(source: [jep at www.irif.fr](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejep/StackExchange/Images/Automaton3.jpg))</sub>

which recognizes exactly the words of even length accepted by $\mathcal{A}$.

If you just want to know whether $L$ contains some word of even length, you could just use a depth-first search algorithm in the automaton $\mathcal{A}_2$ to see whether or not you reach a final state.